# Authenticate Login to Rest api With single click button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, django-rest-framework, onclicklistener, django-authentication

i Edited all my previous question . I solved that long time ago . 
but now i am here and just getting all things done :

i have a login activity :
which makes a call to rest api with credentials .

i have created the login activity it works ok but i have to press the button two times in order to perform some action . i think there is a mistake in my code :

here is my login activity ... if anyone can help me in this i will accept it as answer and will close this link on my stickies....

login.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import java.util.List;



public class login_act extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

List<NameValuePair> params=null;
static String response = null;

private String url = "http://hostname_ip/rest-api/xxxxx/?format=json";
static String u="";
static String p="";
String temp= "";
// User name
private EditText et_Username;
// Password
private EditText et_Password;
// Sign In
private Button bt_SignIn;
// Message
private TextView tv_Message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);


    // Initialization
    et_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u_name);
    et_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    bt_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
    tv_Message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusop);

    bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Stores User name
            String username = String.valueOf(et_Username.getText());
            u=username;

            // Stores Password
            String password = String.valueOf(et_Password.getText());
            p=password;

            new Getlogin().execute();

    }


    });


}


private class Getlogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(login_act.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Signing In...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        String credentials = u + ":" + p;

        try {

                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeBytes(credentials.getBytes());
                httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                temp = response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())

      try {
              pDialog.dismiss();
   if(temp.contains("count")){
              tv_Message.setText("Logged In");

              Intent go = new Intent(login_act.this,Scnd.class);


              Bundle extras = new Bundle();
              extras.putString("status", response);
              extras.putString("user", u);
              extras.putString("pass", p);

              // 4. add bundle to intent
              go.putExtras(extras);
              startActivity(go);

              finish();

          }else
              tv_Message.setText("Invalid username or password");


          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }



    }




}



}
```

i only want if user and pass are ok then intent to new activity . if the user pasword are wrong then display response with incorect user password

but the activity performs it by clicking twice a button . i want to make it single click.. any help ?? i would be thankful.

Comment: You need to pass certain data along with the request.

Comment: Dear, it's not valid api url address. It's html page that's after fetching the content of html, you will get your values from that specific compiler.

Comment: i edited the question kindly review it .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an installation of Newfies-Dialer in order to use the API, in other words the API url will be the one from your own server.

The documentation clearly say API URL => http://HOSTNAME_IP/rest-api/campaigns/

Comment: I dont think it's a good practice to edit your question, then the previous replies doesnt make any sense.

Comment: The problem was i was checking the condition in onCreate() method .
while i was also performing a Async task to call a http service . 

i noticed everything i have to handle on the view supposed to be implemented in onPost() method which Async task provides . 

on above problem thats why it was performing double clicks first to make service cal then the check the condition . 

i just cut paste the condition and put it in onPost method of Async class everything goes amazing now ... edited and fixed to code above as well. it might help someone who is new to Android development . cheers.